# insert values of table in another empty table

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Can someone help me to understand where is the probleme ?
I have two tables the first one is :

```
CREATE TABLE "election-csv" (
"Code du département"           DECIMAL NOT NULL,
.
.
...
);
```

the second one is empty:

```
CREATE TABLE departement (
  code_dpt integer,
  DPT varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY( code_dpt )
);
```

-- error when I want to insert the values from the first table --

```
insert into departement(code_dpt) values (select"Code du département" FROM "election-csv");
```

I get this error :
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"¶  Position : 9

Comment: The insert statement should look like this **insert into departement(code_dpt) select "Code du département" FROM "election-csv";** Also, your use of double quotes may or may not be a problem depending on which DBMS you're using.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MSSQL the INSERT statement should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO departement(code_dpt)
SELECT [Code du département]
FROM election-csv
```